# json_encode with correct format

Tags: php, json

I can't get my json_encode format that I need.

Current Format:

```
{
    "substantiv": [
        {"text":"auto"},
        {"text":"noch ein auto"}
    ],
    "verben":[
        {"text":"auto fahren"}
    ]
}
```

What I need:

```
[
    {
        "type":"substantiv",
        "items": [
            {"text":"auto"},
            {"text":"noch ein auto"}
        ]
    } , {
        "type":"verben",
        "items": [
            {"text":"auto fahren"}
        ]
    }
]
```

My current php code:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    $tmp = array(
        "text" => $row['gtext']
        );

    $data[$row['type']][] = $tmp;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I have tried a few things but just can't figure it out.

Comment: A valid JSON data representation won't duplicate keys in the same nesting level.

Comment: The JSON array you want is invalid, as it contains duplicate property names in the same object. You probably actually need to include an additional nested array to hold each set of `type` and `item` data.

Comment: Use http://jsonlint.com/ to check with the second json result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
    $data[$row['type']][] = array(
        "text" => $row['gtext']
    );
}

$result = array();
foreach($data AS $type => $items) {
    $result[] = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'items' => $items
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "substantiv",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "auto"
            },
            {
                "text": "noch ein auto"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "verben",
        "items": [
            {
                "text": "auto fahren"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

which is the output you'll get from Louis H.'s answer's code.